# If else checking columns in For loop - R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I have a really simple problem that is just stumping me. Im trying to write an if statement in a for loop that checks if a value in a column is greater than another column but for some reason my loop runs once and quits. Here is my code

```
for (i in nrow(cleaned_us_news)){
  school=0
  if(Instructional.expenditure.per.student[i] > Out.of.state.tuition[i]){
    school = school + 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing `1:nrow(cleaned_us_news)`, or alternatively, and slightly better, `seq_along(cleaned_us_news)`.

Comment: You should provide data with your code so people can give you better answers.

Comment: What @DanielAnderson said  plus `school=0` should be out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing the suggestions in the comments above.

```
school=0
for (i in 1:nrow(cleaned_us_news)){
if(Instructional.expenditure.per.student[i] > Out.of.state.tuition[i]){
school = school + 1}
}
```

Comment: For some reason this code is not producing the expected output of 400+ rows. It only loops 8 times.

Comment: It also produces the error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: provide example data. Its most likely data related. just do `dput((cleaned_us_news[1:20,]))` and use `dput` on the other datasets needed.

Comment: You will find pictures of the data in the og post

Comment: Pictures aren't very helpful. It's much better to provide a reproducible example with `dput`. That way, people can actually use your data and make sure the answer they give you works.

Comment: Im unable to add my code using the suggest code snippet above because its too alrge

Comment: @J.McCraiton take a `sample` of the data ie. `duput(sample(x,10))`. If its a `data.frame` then `dput(x[1:10,])`.